# Pause button for Javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a pause button for a JavaScript slideshow that is an infinite loop that displays random images. The error console doesn't throw any errors. The slideshow starts, but the button's value doesn't become pause (I have been playing around with it and it used to). If you press the button twice the slideshow gets faster. The answer is probably lies within a clearTimeout(t); somewhere but I can't seem to make it work. Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var t;
function letsslide(){
     var switcha = document.getElementById("SlideShow");
     if (switcha.getAttribute("value").length == 9) {
           switcha.setAttribute("value", "Pause");
           keeprollin();
     }
     if (switcha.getAttribute("value").length == 5) {
           t = "stopped";
           switcha.setAttribute("value", "Slideshow");
     }
}
function keeprollin(){
     var t = setTimeout("magic()", 2000);
}
function magic(){
     var dazp = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 35);
     document.getElementById('bigpic').setAttribute("src", "images/" + dazp + ".jpg");
     keeprollin();
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<img src="images/9.jpg" id="bigpic" />
<input type="submit" id="SlideShow" value="Slideshow" onclick="letsslide()" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

First, whenever you call `keeprollin()`, it starts a loop.  The loop goes

```
keeprollin()
magic()
keeprollin()
margin()
...infinite
```

You never stop this chain once it starts.  You had the right idea by setting `var t` as the value returned by `setTimeout`, but setting `t` to the value "stopped" doesn't stop this cycle.  You need to use `clearTimeout(t)` to stop the cycle.

Second, the scope of your `var t` is off.  In a function, `var t` will tie the scope of the variable to the function, which won't be accessible in any other function.  If you drop the `var` line, this will tie the value to the `window`, and the `t` variable will be properly set wherever you reference it.

Third, don't use the length of the string to determine what you want to do, just compare strings.  `switcha.getAttribute("value").length==9` should be `switcha.getAttribute("value") == 'Slideshow'`

Fourth, don't name your functions or variables weird or funny names.  You'll save yourself and others headache in the future if you are descriptive in your naming.  It will make your code much easier to read.

... done ranting now :)

Comment: There seems to be another problem :( Thanks for your advice; I will try to make better names :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var t;
function startSlideshow() {
     t = setInterval(magic, 2000);
}
function letsslide(){
     var switcha = document.getElementById("SlideShow");
     if (switcha.getAttribute("value").length == 9) {
           startSlideshow();
           switcha.setAttribute("value", "Pause");
     }
     if (switcha.getAttribute("value").length == 5) {
           clearTimeout(t);
           switcha.value = "Slideshow";
     }
}
function magic(){
     var dazp = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 35);
     document.getElementById('bigpic').setAttribute("src", "images/" + dazp + ".jpg");
}
```

Is probably more what you want.

Comment: Okay, I've changed this a lot now - does the updated code work better for you?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I tried adjusting a few things and it still won't work. I have had enough for tonight. Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var t;

    function letsslide() {
        var switcha = document.getElementById("SlideShow");
        if (switcha.value === "Slideshow") {
            switcha.value = "Pause";
            t = setTimeout(magic, 2000);
        }
        if (switcha.value === "Pause") {
            switcha.value = "Slideshow";
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
    }

    window.letsslide = letsslide;

    function magic() {
        var dazp = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 35);
        document.getElementById('bigpic').src = "images/" + dazp + ".jpg";
        t = setTimeout(magic, 2000);
    }

})();
```

Refactored so that it works. Added a closure so `t` is not global anymore.